Simple heuristics for determining if an attractor is strange?
Apologies if this isn't the right place to post a question like this. I've been browsing online resources for strange attractors people have found, some of them are really beautiful.
A simple attractor called the de Jong attractor is governed by the following map:
$$
x_{n+1}=\sin(ay_n)-\cos(bx_n),\\
y_{n+1}=\sin(cx_n)-\cos(dy_n).
$$
I wrote some basic code with the coefficients $a=1.5,b=2,c=0.5,d=1.5$, which shows a fun pattern.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 10000
drop = 100

def run(a, b, c, d):
    x = np.zeros(N)
    y = np.zeros(N)

    for i in range(N - 1):
        x[i + 1] = np.sin(a * y[i]) - np.cos(b * x[i])
        y[i + 1] = np.sin(c * x[i]) - np.cos(d * y[i])

    plt.scatter(x[drop:], y[drop:], marker='.')
    plt.show()

run(1.5, 2.0, 0.5, 1.5)

My understanding of attractors is minimal but I'd like to learn more. Given a map, I understand that, informally, there are multiple possibilities as $n\to\infty$:

The coordinates converge to a finite set of points.
One or more of the coordinates diverge to $\pm\infty$.
The process exhibits periodic behavior and visits the same set of points over and over or traces the same path over and over.
The process exhibits chaotic behavior, but is bounded.

The maps that are considered visually interesting or appealing are the chaotic ones. I understand that a chaotic system need not be a strange attractor, but I'd like to programmatically identify some strange attractors.
What methods are used to determine/estimate if a system is a strange attractor?
Suppose, in the de Jong attractor map above, I perform a grid search over some range and test various combinations of coefficients. It would be trivial to filter out the cases where the system diverges - perhaps I set a large tolerance, say $10^{10}$, and if either $|x_n|$ or $|y_n|$ exceed $10^{10}$ then I assume the system is divergent. But I'm unsure how to separate chaotic behavior from fixed points/periodic behavior.
I understand there is a notion of Lyapunov exponent, where for a map $f$ in one variable the Lyapunov exponent is given by
$$
L=\frac1N\sum_i\log\left|\frac{\text df}{\text dx}\right|_{x=x_i},
$$
where $L>0$ means chaotic behavior. But how is this extended to systems with more than 1 coordinate? And how should the value of $L$ be interpreted with more than 1 coordinate?
If possible, I'd like to see a minimal example of computing $L$ using the de Jong attractor above. Thanks in advance.

The extension of the Lyapunov exponent to higher dimensions is via the Lyapunov spectrum, which are the eigenvalues of a particular matrix. Chaos is usually determined by the largest of these and there are easy to use packages for computing the largest Lyapunov exponent.

Thanks. I spent the past couple days reading up on the Lyapunov spectrum. Things are a lot clearer now, and I also recreated a numerical method to find the Lyapunov spectrum. If you're able, would you be able to take a look at a new question I posted? It's about the sum of Lyapunov exponents and confusion regarding the Kaplan-Yorke dimension.
